# Why do the Borg want to assimilate every planet in the universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, borg

This is a question that I was wondering about since I was introduced to the Borg in Star Trek: The Next Generation.

Why do the Borg want to assimilate every planet in the universe?

Comment: The Borg assimilates planets?

Comment: Why are Vulcans logical?  Why are Ferengi avaricious?

Comment: _Do_ the Borg want to assimilate every planet in the universe? You haven't provided any evidence of that.

Comment: They don't. They want to assimilate anyone that brings them closer to perfection. Note that they positively refuse to assimilate the Kazon.

Comment: They also attempted to assimilate Earth from an earlier period (First Contact) despite our apparent inferior tech at the time - for reasons explained [in this answer to another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114527/why-would-the-borg-want-to-assimilate-earth-in-the-21st-century/114529#114529).

Comment: @Valorum that sounds like a decent answer

Comment: @Fez - half of one, at any rate.

Comment: It's an interesting question, TBF, is it out of greed to pursue their own expansion of knowledge and technology? Or is it a kind of misguided but well-meaning attempt to bring other civilisations into their (what they believe is superior) society - kind of like colonialists of old (on Earth) trying to bring civilisation to the "savages".

Comment: @komodosp - Given that they refuse to assimilate inferior species, it has to be selfish motives.

Comment: This article discusses this question https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Borg_philosophy

Comment: @user14111 They do, in fact, assimilate entire planets. We saw what happens to earth in the moments before the Enterprise E travels back in time to stop them. It is, in fact, the visual queue that tells the audience that earth has been taken over by them.

Answer (score 7):

The Borg consider all biological lifeforms to be inherently flawed, and see themself as the solution to this. It makes sense from the Borg point of view, leading the Borg to be aggressively territorial. Everything outside of the Borg is an unknown variable and therefore likely to interfere in their march to perfection. So a species is either a source of drones for expansion, or an enemy to be conquered and cleared away.

Comment: Is their definition of "perfection" ever made explicit? It's kind of a relative concept, e.g. someone valuing individual freedom or free will wouldn't see the Borg as perfect.

Comment: That would be a good follow up question to ask, @J-J-J. Go ahead and [ask a whole new question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about it.

Comment: @FreeMan And now, I realize that it has been already asked :) https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121601/what-do-the-borg-think-perfection-is

Comment: "So a species is either a source of drones for expansion, or an enemy to be conquered and cleared away." Or the species possesses technological innovations the Borg want.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back this up?

Comment: @Valorum: Can I offer evidence from the widely varied and inconsistent lore for this fictional pseudo-species? Sure. It's supported by dialogue in First Contact, ST:VOY, and comments the creators have made in industry press or interviews. But it can also be contradicted in other source material, interviews, and show and movie dialogue. Because the truth is that the Borg are whatever the writer needs them to be in the moment of telling a story. I thought ST: PIC was a great show. But it sure played hell with canon in many ways. and that's just one of the branches of the Star Trek family tree.

Comment: @Seneca - So far you've offered no evidence whatsoever, other than airily waving your hand at things they've been in. What dialogue? What interviews and comments?

Comment: @Valorum sure, okay, what part of my claims do you dispute? That the Borg consider themselves perfect and other races imperfect? ST:VOY, Dark Frontier "They left behind their trivial, selfish lives, and they've been reborn with a greater purpose. We've delivered them from chaos into order." - the Borg Queen. Or ST:First Contact, "By assimilating other races into our collective, we are bringing them closer to perfection.", also the Borg Queen.

Comment: @Seneca - Great. Now add those into your answer and you're cooking with gas.

Comment: @Valorum - I feel like it would have been more helpful to just suggest he add quotes to his comment to begin with. The way you phrased it, it sounded more like a challenge.

Comment: @DigitalJedi - I am happy to openly challenge them to write a better answer.

Answer (score 5):

It started out as a race who used technology to increase perfection in itself. Perfection involved cooperation and communication and community. These were carried to pathological extremes, then they decided to extend perfection into the universe. It's a perfect example of too much of something good being bad.

It's absolutely Gene.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This would be a better answer if you attributed the source of this information.

Comment: While this is most likely true in-universe - this answer is very Original Series tropes applied to a TNG example.

Comment: @lucasbachmann Gene Roddenberry was involved in the production of TNG as well, IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

The strength of the Borg in terms of numbers as well as offensive and defensive capabilities is repeatedly represented as far superior than many other groups in Star Trek (thanks to their practice of assimilating anyone with technology that would benefit them). For example, even a single Borg cube is a formidable threat at the [Battle of Wolf 359](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_Wolf_359), killing 11,000 and destroying 39 ships.

In Voyager it's clear that the Borg have their own territory, but Borg ships also show up throughout the show both before and after Voyager enters that territory. But they have the ability to travel so quickly using [transwarp conduits](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Transwarp_conduit) that they could appear suddenly far outside of their own territory. In [Voyager 6x19](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Child%27s_Play_(episode)) a transwarp conduit is located less than a light year from Icheb's home planet, but Voyager's journey through Borg space was all the way back in season 3/4.

Thus it's clear that the Borg could expand their territory and assimilate almost any group, at least in the Delta Quadrant. They have the numbers, the strength, and the ability to travel anywhere. Yet they don't seem to be doing that because otherwise you would have expected the Borg to be running rampant throughout the galaxy. Guinan says the Borg have been around for "thousands of centuries" ([source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Borg#History)). When Seven reawakened the [Vaadwaur](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vaadwaur) they mentioned they had encountered the Borg who at the time (~900 years prior) "they had assimilated only a handful of star systems." 900 years is a lot less than thousands of centuries but it's still a pretty long time.

Additionally, we see many times that the Borg completely ignore people they don't deem to be a threat. Again and again, in both TNG and Voyager, non-Borg are shown walking around on a Borg ship without triggering a defensive response as long as they aren't deemed to be a threat. The implication is that the Borg see themselves as so superior that people walking on their ships could be analogous to insects in your home in that you might ignore them as long as they aren't too much of a problem. The Borg see themselves as so powerful that trespassers on one of their ships aren't necessarily a problem, and they are obsessed with efficiency such that even if they do detect them they couldn't be bothered to do anything about it. That explanation doesn't always make much sense but that's what we're given.

We do know that the Borg are obsessed with perfection. In [Voyager 4x21 "The Omega Directive"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Omega_Directive_(episode)), Seven of Nine is fascinated by the Omega particle because of her time as a Borg and its ability to form a perfect structure. Memory Alpha has an [article on Borg philosophy](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Borg_philosophy) which states:

> The principal philosophy of the Borg Collective was a drive towards achieving a state of "perfection" for themselves and, in their view, all life

However, some species were deemed unworthy, such as the Kazon:

> Their biological and technological distinctiveness was unremarkable; they were unworthy of assimilation
>
> -- Seven of Nine, VOY 4x12 "Mortal Coil"

So while the Borg want to do a lot of assimilation there's clear evidence that they don't "want to assimilate **every** planet in the universe". They could have attacked far more worlds, far more often than they actually were shown to, and they frequently ignore essentially helpless targets that are either categorized as non-threatening or unworthy.

However, we also can't definitively say that the Borg don't want to assimilate everyone. It's possible that given enough time and barring (futile) resistance they would gladly assimilate everyone, even the unworthy, but constraints on resources and strategic considerations limit what they accomplish. But clearly they prioritize efficiency and expect a return on investment so to speak when they assimilate anyone into their collective.

I should note also that the conflict with Species 8472 indicate that the Borg sought to expand even outside of the universe, as the [Fluidic Space](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Fluidic_space) Species 8472 came from was another dimension.

Comment: Guinan says the quote about "Thousands of centuries" and it's not clear whether she's talking about the Borg proper or their biological forerunners

Comment: Thanks, misread that. Does the distinction between the Borg as we know them in Star Trek episodes and their "biological forerunners" really matter in this context? If the Borg as we know them were relatively new and say up until a century ago they were peaceful or something, I wouldn't expect Guinan to phrase it like that. Though the Vaadwaur said the Borg only controlled a handful of systems when the Vaadwaur were active, which was 900 years prior to that Voyager episode. A lot less than thousands of centuries but certainly a long time.

Comment: The Borg are apparently not above using time travel and trying to bootstrap their way to their goals. Terms like "first" become meaningless

Comment: Didn't use the term "first" anywhere… But you make a good point. If the Borg could use time travel and they wanted to assimilate everyone then why wouldn't they just travel back in time with advanced technology to assimilate more worlds? But time travel is probably fairly resource-intensive and extremely risky since one false move could, say, cause the destruction of the Borg in the present.

Comment: @shim There's also the future Federation that are busy fighting anyone who tries altering history using time travel, IIRC.

Comment: Have we ever actually seen them fighting the Borg in the context of time travel? Just curious.